# Regular Expression question that include different letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out Regex that will only accept below strings.

- 7 and 8 numbers: '1234567' and '12345678'
- 7 and 8 numbers that start with T: 'T234567' and 'T2345678'
- 7 and 8 numbers that start with D: 'D234567' and 'D2345678'
- 7 and 8 numbers that start with TD: 'TD34567' and 'TD345678'

Regex I have is:

```
/^(T|[0-9]){1}(D|[0-9]){1}([0-9]){5,6}$/
```

but it's not passing my unit test for 'D234567' and 'D2345678'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
^(?:\d{7,8}|[TD]\d{6,7}|TD\d{5,6})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d{7,8}` Match 7-8 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[TD]\d{6,7}` Match either `T` or `D` and 6-7 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `TD\d{5,6}` Match `TD` and 5-6 digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8NpMZ/1).

Comment: ...or the very slight variant `^(?:\d{2}|[TD]\d|TD)\d{5,6}$`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figure it out right after posted this question. Simply added |D after T| so like this.

`/^(T|D|[0-9]){1}(D|[0-9]){1}([0-9]){5,6}$/`

Comment: Note that it could also match `DD345678`

Comment: That's a valid point. I think I'll be ok with starting DD

Comment: It can also match `1D345678` and in that case you might shorten the pattern to `^[TD0-9][D0-9][0-9]{5,6}$` Or in the other case use `^(?:\d{7,8}|[TD]\d{6,7}|[TD]D\d{5,6})$` https://regex101.com/r/CKipit/1

Comment: `{1}` has no effect, so it can be removed. For example, `(T|D|[0-9]){1}` is the same as `(T|D|[0-9])`. Also, the use of a capture group here may signal to the reader that you will later be using the captured value, but you're not--better to use a non-capture group:  `(?:T|D|[0-9])`

Answer (score 0):

```
const r = /^(?=.{7,8}$)T?D?\d+$/
```

is the simplest solution. Here's a breakdown of what happens:

```
import {lookAhead, maybe, sequence, suffix} from "compose-regexp"

const r = sequence(
  // start anchor
  /^/,
  // are there exactly 7 or 8 characters before the end?
  lookAhead(suffix([7,8], /./), /$/),
  // optionally match a 'T'
  maybe('T'),
  // optionally match a 'D'
  maybe('D'),
  // match numbers until the end
  suffix('+', /\d/),
  /$/
)
```

You can try it out [here](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4IWAA60ATsQAEwKLVoBrAIKEYGACYU5WDAE8ARjD1wYARwCuTamblxrYSAA9WcsNNpY5AHRofKQsAWmkYAHMYVwkAvzR4oTh5aTkAXkcrWzR7AAp4uTkAegA9IooCuSVVDS1tXKcXCFdc5AB2CgAOAF09IvwigEo+gBIhirRCgxMYXIByABU54crp03mAEWWJwsa3eYBqOb6-P21xyqKx+MHE+jhaWHwlCNzpW5z7x5hn2le5pz2OAWODHOTISrSfCMZLzACMACYAMwAFgArAA2NrbSHQ+DEeHI9FYzo4yZyKEwgmLRGozFkwqU-HzBa04nYlbkpmwuYbNn0zmMvE8vlEzEcnYU4XUhaiukMqVUlly4lk7ofO5oB5PF7zMAYaDWcKgvQQrnSwl0jEK7nU-kkgCcNotNLFzqVrqtbVJgsVzN5-Pd-pV4p9kttyrZQZ5svtEtxHo2rLdvojvOTVujMoz6KzLJzAvDLo2IbzvJD1tTLrU9rLNbFWIV8WbaHVlBAFlg1GIEHueAdiDhbA4IEwODw+GowPbQkYzB4bG6rCAA)

With tests aplenty.